# SQL Sum with calculated column

Tags: sql, sum

hello I have an SQL query that selects a SUM value in the first column and I want the second column to be  ( first_column / another_field )

```
select sum(a.amount), (sum(a.amount) / d.total_loading_weight * 1000) as MarginPerTon
from tra_affair a join tra_Delivery d on a.delivery=d.delivery_id
where a.delivery='394179' and a.is_margin='1'
```

I am getting the "not a single-group group function" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: `d.total_loading_weight`.  I'm not sure what you want, but something like:

```
select sum(a.amount),
       (sum(a.amount) / sum(d.total_loading_weight * 1000)) as MarginPerTon
from tra_affair a join
     tra_Delivery d
     on a.delivery = d.delivery_id
where a.delivery = '394179' and a.is_margin = '1';
```

You can also use `min()` or `max()` instead of `sum()` if the values are always the same.

Comment: I dont want to sum the d.total_loading_weight field, I just want to divide the first column field with that.

Comment: @Winston, that doesn't make any sense, though. Which value of d.total_loading_weight is the engine supposed to use, since you've aggregated your results to get the sum of amount?

Comment: every row that is added has the same value on d.total_loading_weight, it is common for all rows hence I want to divide the calculated sum by that number

Comment: Then, instead of the `sum(d.total_loading_weight * 1000)` that Gordon has, you could use either `min(d.total_loading_weight * 1000)` or `max(d.total_loading_weight * 1000)` to get to a singular representation of that value.